# Calculating expectations of sum of martingales

Tags: probability, probability-theory, summation, martingales

Let $\left(X_{n}\right)_{n \geq 0}$ is a martingale with $X_{0}=0$. Assume

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} E\left(\left(X_{n}-X_{n-1}\right)^{2}\right)<\infty .
$$

Show that $X=\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} X_{n}$ exists $P$-a.s.

---

I know how to proceed and have notes (from professor) with answers. However, when I calculate the sum I get

\begin{align*}
    \sum_{n=1}^\infty E((X_n-X_{n-1})^2)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty E(X_n^2+X_{n-1}^2-2X_{n-1}X_n)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty E(X_n^2)+E(X_{n-1}^2)-2E(X_{n-1}X_n)
\end{align*}

Now lets consider the expectation $E(X_{n-1}X_n)$:

\begin{align*}
    E(X_{n-1}X_n)=E(E(X_{n-1}X_n|\mathcal{F}_{n-1}))=E(X_{n-1}E(X_n|\mathcal{F}_{n-1}))=E(X_{n-1}^2)
\end{align*}

Thus we now have

\begin{align*}
    \sum_{n=1}^\infty E(X_n^2)+E(X_{n-1}^2)-2E(X_{n-1}X_n)&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty E(X_n^2)+E(X_{n-1}^2)-2E(X_{n-1}^2)&\\=\sum_{n=1}^\infty E(X_n^2)-E(X_{n-1}^2)
\end{align*}

but my notes are saying that the last sum should be
$$=\sum_{n=1}^\infty E(X_n^2)-E(X_{n-1})$$
which I do not understand why that would be.

Comment: The most likely explanation is that in your notes you just forgot to write the second power.  The expression in your notes is clearly wrong by scaling (every other quantity in sight scales as $c^2$ when $X$ is replaced by $cX$, but the last one does not.)

Comment: @NateEldredge I clarified now as it is not my notes but professors. I answered a comment below which is furthering my confusion: Thanks! the thing is from my understanding the last sum would just be $0$ since the expectation is constant in $n$ for the martingale. Is this incorrect? My question is motivated behind the fact that my professors next line reads:" $=EX_k^2-E(X_0)=E(X_k^2)\leq\sum_{n=1}^\infty E((X_n-X_{n-1})^2)=c$ for some constant $c$ which implies $E(X_k^2)<c$ for all $k\geq 1$ and thus $E(X_n^+)<\infty$."

Comment: It's not 0 as geetha290krm pointed out.  The expression $\sum_{n=1}^\infty E(X_n^2) - E(X_{n-1}^2)$ is equal to $\lim_{n \to \infty} E(X_n^2) - E(X_0^2)$ because the sum telescopes.

Comment: Your professor's notes appear to have several typos.  For instance in the next line you quote, suddenly a variable $k$ has appeared which hasn't been defined.

Comment: @NateEldredge From my understanding it is because the original question is a sum to $\infty$ but he uses $k$ and then finishes the proof with "$=EX_k^2-E(X_0)=E(X_k^2)\leq\sum_{n=1}^\infty E((X_n-X_{n-1})^2)=c$"

Comment: If all the sums to $\infty$ prior to that point were replaced with sums to $k$, then I think everything would make sense, except that $E(X_0)$ in your last line should be $E(X_0^2)$.

Answer (score 1):

Your computation is correct. It shows that $(EX_n^{2})$ is bounded. Any $L^{2}$ bounded martinagle, more generally any uniformly integrable martingale converges almost surely.

[The $n-$th partial sum of $\sum [a_n-a_{n+1}]$ is $a_n-a_0$. In our case it is $EX_n^{2}$ It is given that the series converges, so the partial sums form a bounded sequence. Hence, $(EX_n^{2})$ is bounded].

Comment: Thanks! the thing is from my understanding the last sum would just be $0$ since the expectation is constant in $n$ for the martingale. Is this incorrect? My question is motivated behind the fact that my professors next line reads:" $=EX_k^2-E(X_0)=E(X_k^2)\leq\sum_{n=1}^\infty E((X_n-X_{n-1})^2)=c$ for some constant $c$ which implies $E(X_k^2)<c$ for all $k\geq 1$ and thus $E(X_n^+)<\infty$."

Comment: @mathmath $EX_n$ is a constant but $EX_n^{2}$ is not. I have added some details.

Comment: I am not following exactly @geetha290krm. $\sum_{n=1}^\infty E(X_n^2)-E(X_{n-1}^2)$ would not equal $0$ because the expectation of each $X_k^2$ is not the same? Would my professors argumentation given in the prievous comment then be the same I should use to finish the proof although it would be $=EX_k^2-EX_0^2$?

Comment: No I am not. I am merely trying to understand how to finish the proof given that $=\sum_{n=1}^\infty E(X_n^2)-E(X_{n-1})$ is incorrecnt and it should be $=\sum_{n=1}^\infty E(X_n^2)-E(X_{n-1}^2)$ and the fact that my professors proof uses $=EX_k^2-E(X_0)=E(X_k^2)\leq\sum_{n=1}^\infty E((X_n-X_{n-1})^2)=c$ after that.

Comment: I am just trying to learn. That is all. Sometimes it can be confusing. No reason to be harsh because I am asking questions instead of taking it as is lol. That is beyond strange.

Comment: @mathmath My comment was not meant to be harsh. Please tell me if you have written down the $n-$th partial sum of the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (E(X_n^2)-E(X_{n-1}^2))$?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to apply your calculation to $\sum_{n=1}^k$ instead of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty$.  This would show you that
$$\sum_{n=1}^k E((X_n - X_{n-1})^2) = \sum_{n=1}^k E(X_n^2) - E(X_{n-1}^2) = E(X_k^2) - E(X_0^2)$$
because the second sum telescopes.  But the sum on the left is less than $\sum_{n=1}^\infty E((X_n - X_{n-1})^2)$ for all $k$, so we conclude that $E(X_k^2)$ is bounded.

Comment: I am making this quite difficult but I really want to understand everything. I am ultimately trying to use martingale convergence theorem. Since we know that the sum in question is finite and that the sum to $k$ is equal to $E(X_k^2) - E(X_0^2)$ which is less than or equal to the sum in question this implies that $E(X_k^2)<\infty$ for all $k\geq 1$ which means that $\sup_n E(X_n^+)<\infty$? the last implications are just because it is given that $X_0=0$, right? Then it makes sense.